# Nonresident received the stimulus money for COVID 19 from IRS

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, stimulus

I am a non-resident alien who working in the US.
Yesterday, I received the stimulus money ($1200) due to the COVID 19 from IRS, while I know that as a non-resident, I am not eligible to receive. This is because I filed the incorrect 1040 tax form to IRS before instead of the 1040NR for non-residents and have not file the amended form yet.
So do anyone has the same problem as me?
What I must do with the $1200 stimulus money? Send back to IRS?
Hope to receive support from all of you.

Note - it was received by direct deposit.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Non-residents do not qualify. I do know that there is one exception where if your spouse has a social security number and is a member of the U.S. military during the taxable year. If not, then I would assume it is because of the incorrect tax form.